# I'm trying to create a "Rock, paper, scissors" game, but if-else-if isn't 100% returning the correct values as it should

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, nested, console.log

I'm sort of new to JavaScript, and I'm attempting to create a Rock, paper, scissors game. Here's my code:

```
let choices= ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

    function getComputerChoice() {
      let result= choices[(Math.floor(Math.random()* 3))];
      return result;
      }
    
    console.log(getComputerChoice()); //This first function I made was to have the Computer select one out of the three choices I declared in the global "choices" array. I then used the console log to see the output of what the computer picked. This function worked correctly. 

    function checkWinner(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
     if ((computerSelection === "Rock" && playerSelection === "Rock") ||
         (computerSelection === "Paper" && playerSelection === "Paper") ||
         (computerSelection === "Scissors" && playerSelection === "Scissors")) {
         return "Tie"; 
         } 
           else if ((computerSelection == "Rock" && playerSelection == "Scissors") ||
                    (computerSelection == "Paper" && playerSelection == "Rock") ||
                    (computerSelection == "Scissors" && playerSelection == "Paper")) {
                  return "Computer";
                } else if ((computerSelection == "Scissors" && playerSelection == "Rock") ||
                           (computerSelection == "Rock" && playerSelection == "Paper") ||
                           (computerSelection == "Paper" && playerSelection == "Scissors")) {
                  return "Player";
                } else {
                  return "Try again";
                }
            }  

          let computerSelection= getComputerChoice();
          let playerSelection= "Paper";

     console.log(checkWinner(computerSelection, playerSelection)); //This second function is the function I've been having issues with. I don't understand why, but when I view the output of the "checkWinner" function, half of the time it correctly returns "Tie" when "Paper" is entered into "playerSelection", but then other times it incorrectly returns "Player" when "Paper" is entered, even though obviously that's wrong because it SHOULD return "Tie". Then to make matters worse, half of the time it also returns further nonsensical answers as well, such as "Paper" tying with "Rock" (The Computer's choice), "Paper" tying with "Scissors" (The Computer's choice), "Paper" beating "Scissors" (The Computer's choice), etc.
```

I can't figure out what's wrong here.

For solutions, I've tried using strict equality across all if-else-if statements (That didn't work), regular equality (==) across all if-else-if statements (That didn't work, and seemingly returned worse, more inaccurate results), I rigorously scrutinized my code for any typos, and I couldn't find any obvious syntax errors? I want the computer to return the correct results with 100% accuracy, and not seemingly only around 40%-50% accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the *if-else-if*.

The problem is that checking what the computer picked with `console.log(getComputerChoice())` is not the correct way to do it, since runing this would regenerate the computer's choice.

The correct way to see what the result is, is to put the *result* in the console.log like so: `console.log(result);`

```
function getComputerChoice() {
    let result = choices[(Math.floor(Math.random()* 3))];
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Additionally, you don't have to check for every scenario in case of a TIE, checking `if (computerSelection === playerSelection)` is sufficient.

I don't see why you would need an *else* at the end, if you don't either, then it can be simplified even more, with putting "Player "Win" in the `else`.

```
function checkWinner(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
    if (computerSelection === playerSelection) return "Tie";    
    else if ((computerSelection == "Rock" && playerSelection == "Scissors") ||
            (computerSelection == "Paper" && playerSelection == "Rock") ||
            (computerSelection == "Scissors" && playerSelection == "Paper")) return "Computer";
    else return "Player";
}
```

Comment: Son of a BITCH! I knew I was going wrong somewhere, my biggest issue was that I didn't use the console.log correctly! Thank you so much, it works now! I really appreciate your help, I hope one day I can be as proficient at coding as you are. :D

Comment: No problem. Any time!